# Использование таймера в коде c#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

У меня есть база данных Oracle. И приложение ASP.NET с помощью которого в базу записываются записи и xml-файлы в специальную трансферную таблицу. А отдельное консольное приложение переписывает xml-ки по строкам в финальную таблицу. Вот код:

```
String str = "select T.xmldoc.getClobVal() as xmldoc, TRANSFER_TABLE_ID from Transfer_table T where WRITE_CHECKS <> 1";
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=XE;User ID=Mydb;Password=111292;Unicode=True"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand(str, con))
    {
        using (OracleDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                String xml = reader.GetString(0);
                int id = reader.GetInt32(1);
                XDocument doc;
                using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
                    doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
                OracleCommand com1 = new OracleCommand("insert into Steel_sheet (fuse_id, steel_grades_id, storage_id, length, width, thickness, shipping_date, a_comment, date_manufacture) VALUES ('" + (int)doc.Root.Element("Fuse") + "','" + (int)doc.Root.Element("SteelGrades") + "','" + (int)doc.Root.Element("Storage") + "','" + (string)doc.Root.Element("Length") + "','" + (string)doc.Root.Element("Width") + "','" + (string)doc.Root.Element("Thickness") + "','" + (string)doc.Root.Element("ShippingDate") + "','" + (string)doc.Root.Element("Acomment") + "','" + (string)doc.Root.Element("DateManufacture") + "')", con);  
                com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                OracleCommand com2 = new OracleCommand("update TRANSFER_TABLE set WRITE_CHECKS = 1 where TRANSFER_TABLE_ID = '" + id + "'", con);
                com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Этот код запишет хоть все сразу xml-файлы, которые ещё не записаны. Но проблема в том, что новые записи могут появиться в любой момент. Мне нужно, чтобы консолька висела в рабочем состоянии и била таблицу на наличие новых xml-файлов например каждую секунду. Не разу не пользовался таймерами. Как можно мой код обернуть в таймер, чтобы он отрабатывал каждую секунду к примеру.

Comment: @Андрей помогите пожалуйста с этим вопросом если сможете.

Comment: А почему не вечный цикл и `Thread.Sleep(1000)`?

Comment: @VladD не подумал о нём. А что он будет лучше чем таймер? и не могли бы вы привести пример как это будет выглядеть с моим кодом?

Comment: `while (true) { Thread.Sleep(1000); /* тут чтение из базы */ }`

Comment: Я бы сказал, что это приложение вообще не нужно. XML можно разобрать по полям прямо в Oracle. И следовательно сделать триггер на вставку в Transfer_table, который распарсит XML и вставит запись во вторую таблицу

Comment: @Mike: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD Ну такое решение подошло бы для меня. А переведет ли ТС свой код в pl/sql это большой вопрос... Так что я просто указал направление в котором стоило бы подумать

Comment: @Mike: Ну, возможно, решение с набросками кода помогло бы другим участникам, которые бы потом читали этот вопрос.

Comment: @Mike да можно было бы. Но руководитель дал задание именно что бы сделать либо службу виндовс либо консольку стороннюю которая бы делала это независимо от основной программы. Само собой тригером было бы проще. Но так нельзя вот в чём суть.

Comment: Но в оракле это же не в той же программе, он сам по себе :) Может руководитель просто не в курсе, что это можно сделать в самом оракле...

Comment: @Mike в курсе. Просто я именно должен сделать это службой. В этом задание заключается)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Ваш код

}
```

Comment: только добрался до компьютера, спасибо за вариант сейчас попробую.

Comment: Спасибо большое всё работает.